# How to pick pdf file from document , store it in SQLite and again open it from SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file-handling

I want to pick .pdf file from mobile internal storage , save this file in sqlite as blob type. When i click on 'View' button then retrieve it from database and open it in pdf supported application.

Here i used this code for pick file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

code of onActivityResult

```
                Uri fileuri = data.getData();
                Log.d(TAG, "Document File Uri = " + fileuri);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                FileInputStream fis;
                try
                {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileuri.getPath()));
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int n;
                    while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
                        baos.write(buf, 0, n);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] byteFile = baos.toByteArray();
```

then this byteFile saved into database as a blob type. Now how can i retrieve and open it. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> code of onActivityResult

A `Uri` is not a file. Only if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file` does your code work. Replace your `FileInputStream` with an `InputStream`, where you get that `InputStream` from `getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())`.

Also:

- Your app will crash a lot, as you will not have enough memory to hold the PDF
- Saving large files in `BLOB` columns is an anti-pattern in Android, as the SQLite APIs that we use do not handle large contents very well
- The user will not be happy with you, as you are doing this disk I/O on the main application thread, causing the UI of your app to freeze while that I/O is being performed

> Now how can i retrieve and open it

Reverse the process:

- Get the `byte[]` from the database
- Save that `byte[]` to a file
- Use `ACTION_VIEW` and `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to open the file in the user's chosen PDF viewer

Once again:

- Your app will crash a lot, due to running out of memory trying to load in a large `BLOB`
- Do the I/O on a background thread, so as not to freeze the UI
- Storing large `BLOB` values is an anti-pattern in Android

I strongly recommend that you not store the PDF as a `BLOB` in a database. Either:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `takePersistableUriPermission()` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and save the `Uri` in the database, or
- Copy the PDF to a file, and store some identifier of the file in the database

Comment: thanks for the answer, if i save Uri in database , when i delete original file from storage then how it will be open

Comment: @Jayashri: That will not work. If this is an "import" operation -- where you want your own independent copy of the content, separate from the original -- you would need to make a copy. Though I recommend that you make that copy as a file, not a `BLOB`. Saving the `Uri` is faster than making a copy of the data, and it allows the user to edit that content through other tools, but it does run the risk of the user deleting the content identified by the `Uri`.